# Can I use Samsung Gear 360 as a USB webcam? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, video, webcam

I have a Samsung Gear 360, is there a way to trick Windows into using it as a webcam?

Answer (score 1):

Over a dozen people seem to say the answer is [no](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/Smartphones-Tablets-Wearables/Using-the-gear-360-as-a-pc-camera/td-p/146887)